# Is there any way to put timer/end the serving of infographics automatically in dispacy?

Tags: nlp, visualization, spacy, spacy-3

While running the code with displacy, I see the images being created perfectly as expected.
They are also projected to a server, the address of which is mentioned every time someone runs the code. But the problem I am facing is that the code doesn't stop & maybe keeps on running to maintain the server.
Is there a way to put a timer to that?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no timer option. If you don't want the server you can just not call `displacy.serve`, and instead call `displacy.render`, which just returns the HTML.

See the [`displacy` API docs](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#displacy.serve) for full details.